# Run single test suite with ScalaTest

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I have a simple Scala 2.11.8 + ScalaTest 3.0.1 + SBT project.

I want to run a single ScalaTest Suite class. I created a trivial example test suite `org.example.TestSuite`:

```
package org.example

import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class TestSuite extends FunSuite {
  test("just a simple example test") {
    assert(1 + 1 === 2)
  }
}
```

I can run it in isolation from IntelliJ perfectly fine.

When I try to run this in isolation on the command line:

```
sbt test-only org.example.TestSuite
```

That runs all of my tests.

I look at the docs here: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt

And it says to do exactly what I'm doing, `test` runs everything, while `test-only <qualified suite class names>` runs just specified suites. However, it just isn't working.

This seems outrageously simple but it's just not working and running all tests. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your command line, SBT will take commands with arguments such as yours by enclosing the command and the arguments in quotes:

```
sbt 'test-only org.example.TestSuite'
```

If you enter SBT's command line, then you don't need to specify the quotes and just run your command like:

```
$ sbt
> test-only org.example.TestSuite
```

Note that this last example is how the examples in the documentation link you have posted were meant to be used.

Please note also that in more recent [SBT versions such as 0.13](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html) the command invocation was changed to `testOnly`.